# Docusign code changes after certified inegrator key

Tags: certificate, docusignapi

I have completed the docu-sign certification process and my integrator key in now certified.I have change my url from https://demo.docusign.net to https://docusign.net, which i am using for account authentication.
But still i am redircted to demo.docusign.net for signing process, what other changes need to be done after certification process and before go to  production.
kindly guide me for the same.

Answer (score 0):

The post certification guide can be found [here](https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/API_Certification_Post_11_13_15.pdf)

Your production URL should also be https://{server}.docusign.net/